# Вывести Json object в HTML на JQuery. Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, html, jquery, json, asp.net-core

Сначала покажу более ранению версию на бекенде, которая работала.

```
 public dynamic Get()
    {List<string> myHeadline = new List<string>();
        List<string> myBodyText = new List<string>();

        var s = db2.Post.ToList();

        foreach (var item in s)
        {
            myBodyText.Add(item.BodyText);
            myHeadline.Add(item.Headline);
        }

        var result = new { data1 = myHeadline, data2 = myBodyText};

        return result;
    }
```

И код фроненда

```
 function getData(data) {
    var url = "/api/Blog"
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.data1.length; i++) {
            $("#idfirst").after('<div id="post' + i + '" class="post">' +
                '<div id = "posthead' + i + '" class= "posthead"></div>' +
                '<div id="postbody' + i + '" class="postbody"></div>' +
                '<div id="imgPost' + i + '" class="imgPost"></div></div>');

            $("#posthead" + i).append($('<p>').text(data.data1[i]));
            $("#postbody" + i).append($('<p>').text(data.data2[i]));
            //$("#imgPost" + i).append('<img alt="img" class="imgPost" src="data:image/jpg;base64,' + data.data3 + '" />');
        }

    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    getData();
})
```

Все работает. Все посты с базы выводятся.

Решил добавить фотки и с сделать возвращаем объект как один объект JSON.
Основной код не буду показывать так как в нем не вижу смысла, объект строю из класса где три свойства. Вот он

```
public class GetBlogPost
{
    public GetBlogPost()
    {

    }
    public GetBlogPost(string Head, string Body, List<string> imgPost )
    {
        this.Headline = Head;
        this.BodyText = Body;
        this.Img64 = imgPost;
    }

    public string Headline { get; set; }

    public string BodyText { get; set; }

    public List<string> Img64 { get; set; }
}
```

Далее каждый полученный экземпляр класса пихаю в коллекцию

```
List<GetBlogPost> resultPost = new List<GetBlogPost>();
```

И ее конвертирую в JsonFile

```
var result2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultPost);
return result2;
```

И тут никак не хочет скрипт открывать на вьюхе мой файл.

Побывал всеми комбинациями. Максимум что получалось это в блоке пишется [Object, object]

Вот например вот так

```
$("#posthead" + i).append($('<p>').text(data.result2[i].Headline));
$("#postbody" + i).append($('<p>').text(data.result2[i].BodyText));
```

В студии на точке остановы он адекватно показывает JsonFile(картинку не грузит сюда, ссылка)

http://prntscr.com/kfrbiy

Теперь даже текст не выводит. Фиг с теми фотками, там легко их показать. Как мне распарсить мой объект на фронте в скрипте?

Comment: Сделайте ссылки на изображения, и вставляйте их на страницу в атрибуты `src`.

Comment: та речь идет сейчас не о изображениях..а в общем он не хочет вообще открывать теперь даже текст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так оно работает с $.parseJSON(data)

```
  <script>
  function getData(data) {
  var url = "/api/Blog"
  $.getJSON(url, function (data)
  {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
    {
        $("#idfirst").after('<div id="post' + i + '" class="post">' +
            '<div id = "posthead' + i + '" class= "posthead"></div>' +
            '<div id="postbody' + i + '" class="postbody"></div>' +
            '<div style="width:100%;" id="imgPost' + i + '" class="imgPost"> 
     </div></div>');

        $("#posthead" + i).append($('<p>').text(obj[i].Headline));
        $("#postbody" + i).append($('<p>').text(obj[i].BodyText));

        if (obj[i].Img64.length > 0)
        {
            var x = obj[i].Img64.length;

            for (var y = 0; y < x; y++)
            {
                $("#imgPost" + i).append('<img alt="img" class="imgPost" 
    style="margin:10px;" src="data:image/jpg;base64,' + obj[i].Img64[y] + '" 
    />');
            }
        }  
    }
    });
    }

     $(document).ready(function ()
   {
   getData();
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Что такое "result2" в коде?

```
$("#posthead" + i).append($('<p>').text(data.result2[i].Headline));
```

Наверное должно быть так:

```
$("#posthead" + i).append($('<p>').text(data[i].Headline));
```

Comment: Что такое "result2" в коде? Там же четко видно. Один из возвращаемых вариантов. Там где Json файл. Пробывал и так распарсивать, не получается.